# Broken interface in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've got a problem on my interface. I'm using codeigniter pagination with this one. All data are fetched correctly and returned in a paginated way. Pagination is good also. The main problem is if i go the next page of the pagination, the UI is broken but data are still there. I don't know how to fix this, I'm still new to codeigniter. please help

link using `home` correctly displays the UI and the paginated contents but When link goes `home/index/15` or clicking for the next page results, UI is broken. I've also checked the page source and still its okay. I'm using `<?php echo base_url();?>assets/` to link through my css and js and other assets.

Comment: can you share a screenshot

Comment: @Smoke I've uploaded the screenshots here. please have a look. http://imgur.com/ccNWxYg,alWxE3r,xp4jr3Z#0, http://imgur.com/ccNWxYg,alWxE3r,xp4jr3Z#1, http://imgur.com/ccNWxYg,alWxE3r,xp4jr3Z#2

Comment: there is some changes in pagination library

Comment: what are those some changes?

Comment: Can you please share your pagination controller code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look again on your code if you've really added:

`<?php echo base_url();?>assets/`

Assuming your data is correctly displayed. There might be some links on that page which you haven't changed. That's why your user interface gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put assets parameters inside

When you load the home page your URL looks like

```
localhost/tsa/home/index/15
```

But when you click the page I assume it goes to

```
localhost/tsa/index.php/home/index/15
```

Note the index.php before controller name

> home